# What's the first element in my trigrams?

Tags: r, tokenize, text-mining, tm

Using a trigram-tokenizer from the `RWeka` class

```
> TriGramTokenizer <- function(x){NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=3, max=3))}
```

I tokenized a corpus. Inspection shows that the trigrams look like this:

```
> inspect(tdm_trigram[1:10, 1:3])
A term-document matrix (10 terms, 3 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 10/20
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 17 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

                           Docs
Terms                       en_US.blogs.capped.txt en_US.news.capped.txt
  \u0097 age believe                             0                     1
  \u0095 all tradeable                           0                     1
  \u0093 amazing feat\u0094                      0                     1
  \u0097 appear poised                           0                     1
  \u0096 areas muslim                            0                     1
```

What's the `\u0097` ? I preprocessed my corpus with the usual methods from the `tm` library (stripWhitespace, remove punctuation and so on).

Should I perhaps readin using a different encoding?

Answer (score 2):

These are [Unicode control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) you have interpreted as words.

In older versions of Unicode

- U+0097 was END OF GUARDED AREA
- U+0095 was MESSAGE WAITING
- U+0093 was SET TRANSMIT STATE
- U+0096 was START OF GUARDED AREA

You may want to strip them out before your trigrams